# Pearson's r with no variation in data

Tags: correlation

I'm calculating Pearson's *r* for a set of dichotomous values.

For one item in my data set, all values are identical. Since the variance in *y* will be 0, I will ultimately end up with a division by 0.

I guess I have two questions:

1. Is it fair to say that the correlation coefficient is 0, or is it more valid to say that it cannot be calculated for this item?
2. Is manually checking for 0 variance and treating this as an exception the accepted best practice, or can the formula be modified to cater to this scenario?

Comment: I think we normally say it is undefined.

Comment: @mdewey: Thanks. After searching for some time for a discussion like this, searching for pearson's r undefined gave me [this identical discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9068/pearson-correlation-of-data-sets-with-possibly-zero-standard-deviation). Someone with proper privileges can vote to close this as a duplicate, I suppose.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have voted for closure as you suggest.