# Correlation between two constant variables using the different approaches

Tags: mathematical-statistics, correlation, categorical-data, continuous-data, pearson-r

Let's say we have a vector `X = (1, 1, 1)` and `Y = c(2, 2, 2)`. I want to calculate correlation between those. Taking Pearson correlation brings us nowhere, because standard deviation of both of these equals 0 so we divide by 0. It means that Pearson correlation suggests us that correlation is undefined. However let's use geometric approach which says that correlation coefficient can be calculated as :

[image]

So by substituting our two vectors we get :

$$r = \frac{1\cdot 2 + 1 \cdot 2 + 1 \cdot 2}{\sqrt{1^2+1^2+1^2}\cdot\sqrt{2^2+2^2+2^2}} = \frac{6}{\sqrt{3}\cdot \sqrt{12}} = \frac{6}{\sqrt{36}}=1$$

Why these approaches gives different results, while they are equivalent ? Which result is accurate ?

Comment: [Correlation with a constant](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/267152/correlation-with-a-constant)

Comment: [Pearson correlation of data sets with possibly zero standard deviation?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9068/pearson-correlation-of-data-sets-with-possibly-zero-standard-deviation?rq=1)

Comment: [What is the correlation if the standard deviation of one variable is 0?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18333/what-is-the-correlation-if-the-standard-deviation-of-one-variable-is-0?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @user2974951 who points at very good threads on the topics. There is also this one : [Is there any relationship among cosine similarity, pearson correlation, and z-score?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235673/is-there-any-relationship-among-cosine-similarity-pearson-correlation-and-z-sc/235676), which shows that Pearson correlation is cosine similarity between **centered** vectors, which $X$ and $Y$ in your example are not. If you center them (i.e., substract their means), you'll have $r=\text{cos}(\theta)=0$.